# Cordova Recuperar Numero do Telefone e IMEI Android e iOS

Tags: android, ios, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin

preciso recuperar o numero do telefone e imei com o cordova,
testei alguns plugins mas no meu dispositivo que estou testando nao funcionou algum

meu dispositivo é dual sim e com android 7.1

existe alguma maneira de recuperar o numero do telefone e imei em ambos os casos ?

Comment: Não funcionou, como assim? Está querendo dizer que ocorreu alguma Exception ou alguma outra coisa? Quais plugins tentou?

Comment: undefined retorna, estou tetando com este atualmente cordova-plugin-sim

Comment: Como está seu código que retorna esse erro?

Comment: window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(successCallback, errorCallback);

Comment: tentei esse tambem e sempre caia error https://github.com/vliesaputra/DeviceInformationPlugin

var deviceInfo = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/DeviceInformation");
deviceInfo.get(function(result) {
        console.log("result = " + result);
    }, function() {
        console.log("error");
    });

Comment: e este https://github.com/aquto/cordova-plugin-imei ?

Comment: este ainda nao vou dar uma olhada, obrigado por enquanto

Comment: Entao me perguntei sobre isso agora mesmo, adicionei agora aqui mas nao esta querendo compilar

Comment: erro no xml config, acho que adicionei a permissao de forma errada...
sabe me dizer como adicione corretamente, segundo o plugi a permissao é READ_PHONE_STATE

Comment: consegui amigo, <feature name="NetworkStatus">
         <param name="android-package" value="CDVConnection" />
 </feature>

Comment: Opa, posta como resposta, vai ajudar muita gente, e posta um exemplo de como instalar o plugin também ;)

Comment: vou fazer isso, mas primeiro quero ver totalmente funcional, o plugin retornou diversas informações exceto numero do telefone, estou vendo se tem algum meto especifico mas parece que nao

Comment: Se possível, por favor poste a resposta de como fez

Answer (score 0):

Como foi solicitado, o número do telefone não consegui recuperar por que as vezes retorna nulo, mas o do imei está ai:

plugin: https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim

```
function errorCallback(error)
{
  console.log(error);
}

// Android only: check permission
function hasReadPermission()
{
  window.plugins.sim.hasReadPermission(successCallback, errorCallback);
}

// Android only: request permission
function requestReadPermission()
{
  window.plugins.sim.requestReadPermission(successCallback, errorCallback);
}

function retImei(callback){
  window.plugins.sim.hasReadPermission(
    function isAlowed(alowed){
      if (alowed != true) {
        window.plugins.sim.requestReadPermission(
          function returnedAlowed(returned){
            if (returned === 'OK'){
              window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(
                function getResponse(response){
                  callback(response.deviceId);
                },
                errorCallback
              );
            } else {
              throwError('É necessário permitir acesso ao telefone');
            }
          },
          errorCallback
        );
      } else {
        window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(
          function getResponse(response){
            callback(response.deviceId);
          },
          errorCallback
        );
      }
    }, errorCallback);
  }

  function getImei(){
    retImei(function returnImei(returned){
      myApp.alert(returned);
    })
  }
```